# Firebase cloud functions - observe ref

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I´m completely new to firebase cloud functions. I want to refer to different refs inside a cloud function and get an array with the values of these.

So for example I want to get all the fruits from ('fruits').
similar to (IOS):

```
    ref.observe(.childAdded ... )
```

How do I code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to only trigger a Cloud Function when a new child node is added. Instead you will have to trigger for every write (with `onWrite()`) and then filter inside the code.

The [Firebase documentation on using previous values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) has this example:

> ```
> exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
>     .onWrite(event => {
>       // Only edit data when it is first created.
>       if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
>         return;
>       }
>       // Exit when the data is deleted.
>       if (!event.data.exists()) {
>         return;
>       }
>       ...
> ```

Hmmm.... on second reading of your question, you may be looking how to read from other parts of your database inside a Cloud Function. For that you'd use the Firebase Admin SDK, of which you can find an example in [this sample in the functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/d14e397c8bcd79cb72f18a579492ae7a37dcba61/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js):

> ```
> admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
>   ...
> })
> ```

Comment: Thank You! Yes, I´m more looking for how to get the data of other parts of my database inside a function. However, I don´t want to change that data - just to read it and get it to use a value of it. How can I achieve that? If I got it right the example only shows on how to change it (?). Thank´s

Comment: The Cloud Functions samples show how to access the database from your function. To learn how to read data, study the documentation of the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data